# How do I exclude a directory from my webpack build with vue-cli-3 setup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

I just spent 3 hours putting this line:
`exclude: ['./src/assets/sass']`
in 20 different places. Please tell me where this should go? 
Here is my current setup for the css-loader (`util.js`):

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const config = require('../config')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const packageConfig = require('../package.json')

exports.assetsPath = function (_path) {
  const assetsSubDirectory = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? config.build.assetsSubDirectory
    : config.dev.assetsSubDirectory

  return path.posix.join(assetsSubDirectory, _path)
}

exports.cssLoaders = function (options) {
  options = options || {}

  const cssLoader = {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      sourceMap: options.sourceMap
    }
  }

  const postcssLoader = {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
      sourceMap: options.sourceMap
    }
  }

  // generate loader string to be used with extract text plugin
  function generateLoaders (loader, loaderOptions) {
    const loaders = options.usePostCSS ? [cssLoader, postcssLoader] : [cssLoader]

    if (loader) {
      loaders.push({
        loader: loader + '-loader',
        // exclude: ['./src/assets/sass'],
        options: Object.assign({}, loaderOptions, {
          sourceMap: options.sourceMap
        })
      })
    }

    // Extract CSS when that option is specified
    // (which is the case during production build)
    if (options.extract) {
      return ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        use: loaders,
        fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
      })
    } else {
      return ['vue-style-loader'].concat(loaders)
    }
  }

  // https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/extract-css.html
  return {
    css: generateLoaders(),
    postcss: generateLoaders(),
    less: generateLoaders('less'),
    sass: generateLoaders('sass', { indentedSyntax: true }),
    scss: generateLoaders('sass'),
    stylus: generateLoaders('stylus'),
    styl: generateLoaders('stylus')
  }
}

// Generate loaders for standalone style files (outside of .vue)
exports.styleLoaders = function (options) {
  const output = []
  const loaders = exports.cssLoaders(options)

  for (const extension in loaders) {
    const loader = loaders[extension]
    output.push({
      test: new RegExp('\\.' + extension + '$'),
      exclude: ['./src/assets/sass'],
      use: loader
    })
  }

  return output
}

exports.createNotifierCallback = () => {
  const notifier = require('node-notifier')

  return (severity, errors) => {
    if (severity !== 'error') return

    const error = errors[0]
    const filename = error.file && error.file.split('!').pop()

    notifier.notify({
      title: packageConfig.name,
      message: severity + ': ' + error.name,
      subtitle: filename || '',
      icon: path.join(__dirname, 'logo.png')
    })
  }
}
```

Here is what my base webpack file looks like:

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const config = require('../config')
const vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}



module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  entry: {
    app: ['babel-polyfill','./src/main.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')],
      },
      // {
      //   test: /\.scss$/,
      //   exclude: ['./src/assets/sass']
      // },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    // prevent webpack from injecting useless setImmediate polyfill because Vue
    // source contains it (although only uses it if it's native).
    setImmediate: false,
    // prevent webpack from injecting mocks to Node native modules
    // that does not make sense for the client
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty'
  }
}
```

Here is the vue-webpack file:

```
'use strict'
const utils = require('./utils')
const config = require('../config')
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const sourceMapEnabled = isProduction
  ? config.build.productionSourceMap
  : config.dev.cssSourceMap

module.exports = {
  loaders: utils.cssLoaders({
    sourceMap: sourceMapEnabled,
    extract: isProduction
  }),
  cssSourceMap: sourceMapEnabled,
  cacheBusting: config.dev.cacheBusting,
  transformToRequire: {
    video: ['src', 'poster'],
    source: 'src',
    img: 'src',
    image: 'xlink:href'
  }
}
```

Presumably this line should go in one of these files unfortunately it is not preventing webpack from attempting to build it (and therefore failing to do so)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out after much experimentation that if I removed this line from the first snippet:
`scss: generateLoaders('sass'),` 
The reason seems to be that even though the files in this directory are never used in my project, the loader attempts to load them because of the file name, so by not having a loader it does not attempt that and no other errors are thrown since the file is not used. 
Presumably if one wanted to keep the loader and exclude a specific directory then you would need to put in a condition on this section in the first snippet:

```
for (const extension in loaders) {
    const loader = loaders[extension]
    //enter your condition here, i.e. if(loader === something) then push an object 
    // with "exclude"
    output.push({
      test: new RegExp('\\.' + extension + '$'),
      exclude: ['./src/assets/sass'],
      use: loader
    })
  }
```